# how to start a service like localphone.com

Tags: voip, phone-call

I would like to know how the site www.localphone.com works. I am asking about the technical part

We create an account,buy credit and we will click on MAKE CALL. Then localphone will call in our registered mobile number and once we pick the call,then they will connect to the destination. ie, there is no need of internet to make call.

Additionally they also offer VoIP calls.

so can some one explain me what all technically requirements are there to start a service like localphone (non voip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is called PBX ( private branch exchange) , there is no requirement for internet, basically it has own telephony exchange and call each source and destination and connect them within exchange. They can also make call conference etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pbx

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_telephone_system

Comment: is both hardware and software required or just software?

Comment: You can contact some PBX services provider, they can provide hardware and software. Even they provide IVR system as well. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response